# How to pass dynamic value in jquery plugin attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins, angular2-directives

I am using numscroller.js and have passed the dynamic value in jquery button click, but it's not working.

Jquery Library:

http://demo.tinywall.net/numscroller/

```
 <p>
            <button>Counter</button>
                <span id="myPercents"><span class='numscroller' data-min='1' data-max='50' data-delay='3' data-increment='1'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>%</span>
          </p>
```

```
    $("button").click(function(){
      alert('2');
      $(".numscroller").attr("data-min", '1');
      $(".numscroller").attr("data-max", '500');
  });
```

and Another question can i able to pass the value from angular component.

```
import { Component ,OnInit} from '@angular/core';

declare var $:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit{
totalvisitors = 1000; // dynamic value
dayvisitors = 10; // dynamic value
}
```

markup:

I have an angular4 component when the page loads it shows the total visitors count increasing on the page.How to communicate dynamic pass inside numscroller.

app.component.ts

when using dynamic passing

```
<span class='numscroller' data-min='1' data-max="totalvisitors" data-delay='5' data-increment='10'>1000</span>
```

Comment: If you're using Angular I'd strongly suggest you don't use jQuery at all.

Comment: @Rory mcCrossan i agree your answer .. but clients need this library they don't want to change the library , so i have found some angular library support the feature , but they don't need . so for my investigation have its support inside angular2 or 4 for dynamic passing.